# Decoration marking arrow style ignored in custom node shape?

Tags: tikz-pgf, scaling, tikz-arrows, decorations

I have this dimension line macro which I've put together from examples here; and as it should be visible from the MWE (below) output:

[image: test05a]

... it works just dandy fine when called from "regular" `\draw` in a `{tikzpicture}` (A) - however, when the `\draw` is part of call to a custom node shape `\pgfdeclareshape{myshape}{...` - then both the rotation, and the scale options of the arrow are *ignored*, when the dimension line (M) is drawn ?! (EDIT: I just tried the color parameter too; weirdly, that one is *not* ignored ??)

Why does this happen - and how can I get this arrowed line to work also in a custom shape, as it does in normal circumstances?

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,tightpage,border=1bp]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pagecolor{yellow!15} % ignored with preview, but not w/ varwidth

\begin{document}

Hello:

\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzset{
  %instead of dimen/.style={, using tconarrC for dimen!
  declare function={multip(\a,\b)=\a*\b;}, % otherwise cannot use pgfmathparse here
  tconarrC/.style n args={5}{
    line width=#3,
    draw=#5,
    decoration={markings,
      mark=at position 0 with {\arrow[rotate=180,scale=#4,fill=#5]{#1}}, 
      mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[scale=#4,fill=#5]{#2}}, 
    },
    shorten >={multip(#4,#3)},
    shorten <={multip(#4,#3)},
    postaction={decorate},
  },
  tconarrC/.default={latex}{latex}{3pt}{1.3}{black},
  dimen/.style={|-|,
    tconarrC={latex}{latex}{\pgflinewidth}{2.0}{black},
    every rectangle node/.style={midway,},
  },
  minbox/.style={shape=rectangle,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum size=0pt},
} % end tikzset
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{myshape}{ %
  \inheritsavedanchors[from={rectangle}] %
  \inheritbackgroundpath[from={rectangle}] %
  \inheritanchorborder[from={rectangle}] %
  \foreach \x in {center,north,north east,north west,south,south east,south west,east,west}{ %
    \inheritanchor[from={rectangle}]{\x} %
  } %
  \backgroundpath{ %
    \edef\ename{\tikz@fig@name} %
    \node[rectangle,minimum size=10pt,draw] (\ename-A) at (\ename.east) {};
    \node[rectangle,minimum size=10pt,draw] (\ename-B) at (\ename.west) {};
  }
  \foregroundpath{ %
    % here, minbox must have a shape (e.g. rectangle) defined!
    % else ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255].
    \draw[dimen] (\ename-A.center) -- (\ename-B.center)
      node[minbox,above=0pt] (\ename-L) {M}
    ;
  }
}

\node[fill] (origin) at (0,0) {};

\node[myshape,minimum size=2cm,anchor=south west] (tshape) at (1,1) {};

\draw[dimen] ($(tshape-A)-(0,2em)$) -- ($(tshape-B)-(0,2em)$) node[above=0pt] {A};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I came to some sort of a workaround - which looks OK (except the dimension line endpoints don't seem to be *exactly* at node centers):

[image: test05b.png]

... achieved by trying to throw in any `\pgf*` command I could find in the manual, related to coordinate system transformations, randomly in the code in brute force fashion, and then seeing their effect (see comments in MWE below)

The trick is, essentially, to do this:

```
decoration={markings,
  mark=at position 0 with {%
    \pgftransformresetnontranslations %
    \pgftransformscale{#4} % 
    \arrow[sloped,rotate=0,scale=1,fill=#5]{#1}; %
  },
  mark=at position 1 with {% 
    %\pgftransformresetnontranslations  % NOT HERE!
    \pgftransformscale{#4} % 
    \arrow[sloped,scale=1,fill=#5]{#2};
  },
},
```

Why? Beats me - I have no idea; *especially* since if I print out the transformation matrices from these points in the code, they are *exactly* the same (the scaling part, not the translation one), no matter where they're called from; the MWE below prints out:

```
pos 0: pgfgettransform: {-1.0}{0.0}{0.0}{-1.0}{90.95824pt}{62.30548pt}; pgf@pt@
aa, pgf@pt@ba, pgf@pt@ab, pgf@pt@bb: -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0
pos 1: pgfgettransform: {-1.0}{0.0}{0.0}{-1.0}{33.65276pt}{62.30548pt}; pgf@pt@
aa, pgf@pt@ba, pgf@pt@ab, pgf@pt@bb: -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0
pos 0: pgfgettransform: {-1.0}{0.0}{0.0}{-1.0}{90.95824pt}{42.30545pt}; pgf@pt@
aa, pgf@pt@ba, pgf@pt@ab, pgf@pt@bb: -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0
pos 1: pgfgettransform: {-1.0}{0.0}{0.0}{-1.0}{33.65276pt}{42.30545pt}; pgf@pt@
aa, pgf@pt@ba, pgf@pt@ab, pgf@pt@bb: -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0
```

Well, hope someone will eventually clarify this properly - in the meantime, I hope this was it with dimension arrow problems.

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,tightpage,border=1bp]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pagecolor{yellow!15} % ignored with preview, but not w/ varwidth

\begin{document}

Hello:

\begin{tikzpicture}

\makeatletter
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185444/
\gdef\tout{}\gdef\trfm{}
\gdef\typeoutMyInfoString#1{%
  \pgfgettransform{\trfm}%
  \edef\tout{#1 %
    pgfgettransform: \trfm ; %
    pgf@pt@aa, pgf@pt@ba, pgf@pt@ab, pgf@pt@bb: \pgf@pt@aa, \pgf@pt@ba, \pgf@pt@ab, \pgf@pt@bb %
  }
  \typeout{\tout} %
}
\makeatother

\gdef\myset{
\tikzset{ %
  %instead of dimen/.style={, using tconarrC for dimen!
  declare function={multip(\a,\b)=\a*\b;}, % otherwise cannot use pgfmathparse here
  tconarrC/.style n args={5}{
    line width=##3,
    draw=##5,
    decoration={markings,
      mark=at position 0 with {%
        \typeoutMyInfoString{pos 0:}%
        % (c0)
        \pgftransformresetnontranslations %
        % (c1)
        \pgftransformscale{##4} % this works the same for both;
                                % so don't scale the arrow
        \arrow[sloped,rotate=0,scale=1,fill=##5]{##1}; % (c3)
      },
      mark=at position 1 with {% 0.999999
        % here we seemingly have correct orientation between M and A;
        % just the scale is different; so only scale needed.
        \typeoutMyInfoString{pos 1:}%
        %\pgftransformresetnontranslations  % causes both arrows to
                                            % rotate/orient wrongly!
                                            % without it, all is correct
        \pgftransformscale{##4} % this works the same for both;
                                % so don't scale the arrow
        \arrow[sloped,scale=1,fill=##5]{##2};
      },
    },
    shorten >={multip(##4,##3)},
    shorten <={multip(##4,##3)},
    reset transform/.code={},%\pgftransformreset}, %is called anyway
    %decorate, % cannot, no line is drawn
    %preaction={reset transform,decorate}, % meh
    postaction={reset transform,decorate},
  },
  tconarrC/.default={latex}{latex}{3pt}{1.3}{black},
  dimen/.style={|-|,
    tconarrC={latex}{latex}{\pgflinewidth}{2.0}{gray},
    every rectangle node/.style={midway,},
  },
  minbox/.style={shape=rectangle,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum size=0pt},
} % end tikzset
} % end gdef
\myset % execute
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{myshape}{ %
  \inheritsavedanchors[from={rectangle}] %
  \inheritbackgroundpath[from={rectangle}] %
  \inheritanchorborder[from={rectangle}] %
  \foreach \x in {center,north,north east,north west,south,south east,south west,east,west}{ %
    \inheritanchor[from={rectangle}]{\x} %
  } %
  %\myset % ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/dimen'
  \backgroundpath{ %
    \edef\ename{\tikz@fig@name} %
    \node[rectangle,minimum size=10pt,draw] (\ename-A) at (\ename.east) {};
    \node[rectangle,minimum size=10pt,draw] (\ename-B) at (\ename.west) {};
  }
  \foregroundpath{ %
    %\myset % ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/dimen'
    % here, minbox must have a shape (e.g. rectangle) defined!
    % else ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255].
    \draw[dimen] (\ename-A.center) -- (\ename-B.center)
      node[minbox,above=0pt] (\ename-L) {M}
    ;
  }
} % declareshape
\makeatother

\node[fill] (origin) at (0,0) {};

\node[myshape,minimum size=2cm,anchor=south west] (tshape) at (1,1) {};

\draw[dimen]
  ($(tshape-A.center)-(0,2em)$) -- ($(tshape-B.center)-(0,2em)$)
  node[above=0pt] {A};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


        % (c0)
%         \pgfgettransformentries{\ta}{\tb}{\tc}{\td}{\tx}{\ty} %
%         \pgfusepath{draw,stroke} %
%         \pgfinterruptpath % nothing
        %\tikz\draw[-latex](\tx,\ty) ; % completely messes up sizing
%         \draw[-latex](0pt,0pt) ; % sizing presserved; \tx,\ty moves to bottom left corner; 0,0 is relative; arrows points "up" like this, unscaled! ,rotate=90 is ignored
%         \node[draw=none,rotate=180,inner sep=0pt] (ti) {\tikz\draw[-latex](0pt,0pt);}; % somewhat messed up; same at at (0pt,0pt); M leaks?

        % (c1)
%         \node[rotate=-90,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum size=0pt,anchor=west] (ti) {\tikz\draw[-latex](0pt,0pt);}; % rotate works here, but opposite directions A and M? with \pgftransformresetnontranslations they finally orient the same!
%         \node[draw=none,rotate=180,inner sep=0pt,anchor=center] (ti) {\tikz\arrow{latex};}; % somewhat messed up
%         \draw[-latex,rotate=180](0pt,0pt); % same rotation, but rotate ignored!

        % (c3)
% with rotate=180, A is correct, M ignores;  with rotate=0, A only rotates, M stays same (bad) ; with \pgftransformresetnontranslations and rotate=0, finally both arrows point the same way correctly
%         \endpgfinterruptpath %
```