# Controlling the orientation of a Tikz decoration markings arrow?

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating, tikz-arrows, decorations

I thought that my woes in [Decoration marking arrow style ignored in custom node shape?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185386/decoration-marking-arrow-style-ignored-in-custom-node-shape) were temporarily solved, but alas: if I do a dimension line `(A) -- (B)`, then all is fine; but if I do `(B) -- (A)`, then one of the arrows gets inverted; the output of the MWE below is:

[image: test06a]

Now, as I saw in [How to draw just the arrow tip in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38292/how-to-draw-just-the-arrow-tip-in-tikz/38300#38300), just the arrow tip can be reproduced with, say:

```
\draw[-latex] (0.4,0.4);
```

This is a line with length 0, starting at (0.4,0.4); interestingly, in the MWE, the result of this command is an arrow pointing *up* (and the answer at previous link uses `node[rotate=90,inner sep=0pt] {\tikz\draw[-triangle 90](0,0) ;};` to rotate the arrow).

My first question is: can the orientation of an arrow be changed for a zero length line, *without* wrapping it in a context (like `\node`, or `{scope}` etc) that would rotate it wholesale?

My second question is - can the dimension line code be somehow fixed, so the correct dimension line arrows are displayed, regardless if the line drawing goes in the `(A) -- (B)` or the opposite `(B) -- (A)` direction?

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,tightpage,border=1bp]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pagecolor{yellow!15} % ignored with preview, but not w/ varwidth

\begin{document}

Hello:

\begin{tikzpicture}

\makeatletter
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185444/
\gdef\tout{}\gdef\trfm{}
\gdef\typeoutMyInfoString#1{%
  \pgfgettransform{\trfm}%
  \edef\tout{#1 %
    pgfgettransform: \trfm ; %
    pgf@pt@aa, pgf@pt@ba, pgf@pt@ab, pgf@pt@bb: \pgf@pt@aa, \pgf@pt@ba, \pgf@pt@ab, \pgf@pt@bb %
  }
  \typeout{\tout} %
}
\makeatother

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/185454/2595
\tikzset{ %
  declare function={multip(\a,\b)=\a*\b;}, % otherwise cannot use pgfmathparse here
  tconarrC/.style n args={5}{
    line width=#3,
    draw=#5,
    decoration={markings,
      mark=at position 0 with {%
        \typeoutMyInfoString{pos 0:}%
        \pgftransformresetnontranslations %
        \pgftransformscale{#4} %
        \arrow[sloped,rotate=0,scale=1,fill=#5]{#1}; % (c3)
      },
      mark=at position 1 with {% 0.999999
        \typeoutMyInfoString{pos 1:}%
        \pgftransformscale{#4} %
        \arrow[sloped,scale=1,fill=#5]{#2};
      },
    },
    shorten >={multip(#4,#3)},
    shorten <={multip(#4,#3)},
    reset transform/.code={},
    postaction={reset transform,decorate},
  },
  tconarrC/.default={latex}{latex}{3pt}{1.3}{black},
  dimen/.style={|-|,
    tconarrC={latex}{latex}{\pgflinewidth}{2.0}{gray},
    every rectangle node/.style={midway,},
  },
  minbox/.style={shape=rectangle,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum size=0pt},
} % end tikzset
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{myshape}{ %
  \inheritsavedanchors[from={rectangle}] %
  \inheritbackgroundpath[from={rectangle}] %
  \inheritanchorborder[from={rectangle}] %
  \foreach \x in {center,north,north east,north west,south,south east,south west,east,west}{ %
    \inheritanchor[from={rectangle}]{\x} %
  } %
  \backgroundpath{ %
    \edef\ename{\tikz@fig@name} %
    \node[rectangle,minimum size=10pt,draw] (\ename-A) at (\ename.east) {};
    \node[rectangle,minimum size=10pt,draw] (\ename-B) at (\ename.west) {};
  }
  \foregroundpath{ %
    \draw[dimen]
      (\ename-A.center) -- (\ename-B.center)
      node[minbox,above=0pt] (\ename-L) {M$_1$}
    ;
    \draw[dimen]
      ($(\ename-B.center)-(0,1em)$) -- ($(\ename-A.center)-(0,1em)$)
      node[minbox,above=0pt] (\ename-L) {M$_2$}
    ;
  }
} % declareshape
\makeatother

\node[fill] (origin) at (0,0) {};
\draw[-latex] (0.4,0.4);

\node[myshape,minimum size=2cm,anchor=south west] (tshape) at (1,1) {};

\draw[dimen]
  ($(tshape-A.center)-(0,3em)$) -- ($(tshape-B.center)-(0,3em)$)
  node[above=-1pt] {A};
\draw[dimen]
  ($(tshape-B.center)-(0,4em)$) -- ($(tshape-A.center)-(0,4em)$)
  node[above=-1pt] {B};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I added a couple of parameters to dirty hack your code:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,tightpage,border=1bp]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pagecolor{yellow!15} % ignored with preview, but not w/ varwidth

\begin{document}

Hello:

\begin{tikzpicture}

\makeatletter
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185444/
\gdef\tout{}\gdef\trfm{}
\gdef\typeoutMyInfoString#1{%
  \pgfgettransform{\trfm}%
  \edef\tout{#1 %
    pgfgettransform: \trfm ; %
    pgf@pt@aa, pgf@pt@ba, pgf@pt@ab, pgf@pt@bb: \pgf@pt@aa, \pgf@pt@ba, \pgf@pt@ab, \pgf@pt@bb %
  }
  \typeout{\tout} %
}
\makeatother

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/185454/2595
\tikzset{ %
  declare function={multip(\a,\b)=\a*\b;}, % otherwise cannot use pgfmathparse here
  tconarrC/.style n args={7}{
    line width=#3,
    draw=#5,
    decoration={markings,
      mark=at position 0 with {%
        \typeoutMyInfoString{pos 0:}%
        \pgftransformresetnontranslations %
        \pgftransformscale{#4*#7} %
        \arrow[sloped,scale=#6,fill=#5]{#1}; % (c3)
      },
      mark=at position 1 with {% 0.999999
        \typeoutMyInfoString{pos 1:}%
        \pgftransformscale{#4} %
        \arrow[sloped,scale=1,fill=#5]{#2};
      },
    },
    shorten >={multip(#4,#3)},
    shorten <={multip(#4,#3)},
    reset transform/.code={},
    postaction={reset transform,decorate},
  },
  tconarrC/.default={latex}{latex}{3pt}{1.3}{black}{1}{1},
  dimen/.style n args={2}{|-|,
    tconarrC={latex}{latex}{\pgflinewidth}{2.0}{gray}{#1}{#2},
    every rectangle node/.style={midway,},
  },
  dimen/.default={1}{1},
  minbox/.style={shape=rectangle,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum size=0pt},
} % end tikzset
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{myshape}{ %
  \inheritsavedanchors[from={rectangle}] %
  \inheritbackgroundpath[from={rectangle}] %
  \inheritanchorborder[from={rectangle}] %
  \foreach \x in {center,north,north east,north west,south,south east,south west,east,west}{ %
    \inheritanchor[from={rectangle}]{\x} %
  } %
  \backgroundpath{ %
    \edef\ename{\tikz@fig@name} %
    \node[rectangle,minimum size=10pt,draw] (\ename-A) at (\ename.east) {};
    \node[rectangle,minimum size=10pt,draw] (\ename-B) at (\ename.west) {};
  }
  \foregroundpath{ %
    \draw[dimen]
      (\ename-A.center) -- (\ename-B.center)
      node[minbox,above=0pt] (\ename-L) {M$_1$}
    ;
    \draw[dimen={-1}{-1}]
      ($(\ename-B.center)-(0,1em)$) -- ($(\ename-A.center)-(0,1em)$)
      node[minbox,above=0pt] (\ename-L) {M$_2$}
    ;
  }
} % declareshape
\makeatother

\node[fill] (origin) at (0,0) {};
\draw[-latex] (0.4,0.4);

\node[myshape,minimum size=2cm,anchor=south west] (tshape) at (1,1) {};

\draw[dimen]
  ($(tshape-A.center)-(0,3em)$) -- ($(tshape-B.center)-(0,3em)$)
  node[above=-1pt] {A};
\draw[dimen={-1}{1}]
  ($(tshape-B.center)-(0,4em)$) -- ($(tshape-A.center)-(0,4em)$)
  node[above=-1pt] {B};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I find your code quite complicated. Why don't you use simple styles? Like here:

```
\documentclass[border=1bp]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{
    myarrows/.style={            
        gray,
        {|[scale=1.5]Latex[scale=2, sep=-1pt]}-{Latex[scale=2, sep=-1pt]|[scale=1.5]}
        },
    myarrowswithsquares/.style={
        myarrows,
        tips=true,
        preaction={Square[black,open,sep=-5.5pt, scale=3]}-{Square[black,open,sep=-5.5pt, scale=3]},
        },
    mynode/.style={            
        above=.5pt, midway, black,
        inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,
        },
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[rectangle,minimum size=2cm,anchor=south west] (tshape) at (1,1) {};
        \draw[myarrowswithsquares] (tshape.east) -- (tshape.west)
            node[mynode] {$\textrm{M}_1$};
        \draw[myarrows]
            ([yshift=-1em]tshape.west) -- ([yshift=-1em]tshape.east)
            node[mynode] {$\textrm{M}_2$};
        \draw[myarrows] ([yshift=-3em]tshape.west) -- ([yshift=-3em]tshape.east) node[mynode] {A};
        \draw[myarrows] ([yshift=-4em]tshape.east) -- ([yshift=-4em]tshape.west) node[mynode] {B};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]